# auto.arima and DLM give different values for loglikelihood

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, dlm

I want to estimate an ARIMA model on my timeseries, then represent it in state space format, mainly because it will be more responsive to change in pattern.
I used `auto.arima` from `forecast` package to find the best ARIMA, and then, if it didn't need differencing, tried to estimate the same ARMA using `dlm`package.

```
fit.arima <- auto.arima(training_data_list, seasonal = FALSE)
Series: training_data_list 
ARIMA(1,0,1) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1
      0.8247  -0.4913
s.e.  0.0395   0.0618

sigma^2 estimated as 489.7:  log likelihood=-3161.25
AIC=6328.5   AICc=6328.53   BIC=6342.15
```

Now the same thing using `dlm` package:

```
test.model.arma <- function(u){
  arma  <- dlmModARMA(ar = ARtransPars(u[1]), ma = u[2], sigma2 = exp(u[3]))   # ma = c(u[4]),
  return(arma)
}
init <-c(rep(0,3))
outMLE2 <- dlmMLE(training_data_list, init, test.model.arma,method = "Nelder-Mead")
# outMLE2 <- dlmMLE(training_data_list, init, test.model.arma)
if(outMLE2$convergence != 0) {print("MLE did NOT converge!")}

dlmModel4 <- test.model.arma(outMLE2$par)
```

Now the loglikelihood from the later one is $2523.158$, while the `auto.arima` gives $3161.25$. the coefficients for $ar$ and $ma$ are very close, so I think it might be unlikely to be the reason.

```
dput(training_data_list)
structure(c(0.92, 3.76, 2.64, 2.72, -4.48, 4.68, 6.2, 4.16, 22.32, 
28.96, 5.72, 3.44, 29.56, 37.28, 38.16, 31.28, 32.04, 21.32, 
2.88, 7.08000000000001, 52.32, 9.80000000000001, 8.56, 2.24000000000001, 
29.8, 49.2, 23.88, 42.32, -0.08, 3.76, -0.359999999999999, 2.72, 
8.52, 26.68, 7.2, -18.84, -13.68, -3.03999999999999, 10.72, -14.56, 
-16.44, 44.28, -17.84, -8.72000000000003, 3.04000000000002, 30.32, 
-21.12, -13.92, -3.68000000000001, -17.2, -16.44, -7.75999999999999, 
39.8, -1.80000000000001, 25.88, 9.31999999999999, -0.08, 1.76, 
2.64, -5.28, -4.48, 3.68, 1.2, -10.84, -21.68, -1.03999999999999, 
-6.28, 22.44, 62.56, 27.28, 1.16000000000003, -8.72000000000003, 
23.04, -11.68, -40.12, -33.92, -43.68, -26.2, -58.44, 5.24000000000001, 
-33.2, -18.8, -48.12, -57.68, -0.08, 3.76, -2.36, -7.28, -1.48, 
-1.32, 2.2, -6.84, 14.32, 23.96, -6.28, -11.56, -13.44, 14.28, 
-38.84, -31.72, 4.04000000000002, 4.31999999999999, 24.88, -3.91999999999999, 
-19.68, 30.8, 13.56, 4.24000000000001, 22.8, 36.2, 44.88, -17.68, 
-0.08, -1.24, -4.36, -1.28, -5.48, 7.68, 1.2, 14.16, -1.68000000000001, 
9.96000000000001, -3.28, 8.44, 59.56, 33.28, 23.16, 72.28, 48.04, 
36.32, 41.88, 7.08000000000001, 13.32, 20.8, 19.56, -0.759999999999991, 
-4.19999999999999, 31.2, 40.88, -10.68, -0.08, 6.76, 2.64, 2.72, 
7.52, 1.68, 1.2, -8.84, -7.68000000000001, 11.96, 31.72, -5.56, 
38.56, 27.28, -15.84, 60.28, 21.04, -22.68, 33.88, 55.08, 41.32, 
24.8, 6.56, 20.24, 60.8, 36.2, -9.12, 42.32, -0.08, 2.76, 2.64, 
1.72, -1.48, 2.68, 8.2, -18.84, -24.68, -4.03999999999999, 2.72, 
-31.56, -9.44, -11.72, -48.84, -5.72000000000003, 2.04000000000002, 
-19.68, -2.12, 27.08, 7.31999999999999, -22.2, 42.56, 11.24, 
9.80000000000001, 17.2, 25.88, 55.32, -0.08, -3.24, -4.36, 1.72, 
-6.48, 0.68, -0.799999999999997, 6.16, -13.68, -14.04, -2.28, 
12.44, -24.44, -15.72, 13.16, 1.27999999999997, -16.96, -40.68, 
-76.12, -50.92, -49.68, -58.2, -42.44, -36.76, -8.19999999999999, 
-43.8, -71.12, -62.68, -0.08, -3.24, -2.36, -1.28, 8.52, 4.68, 
-0.799999999999997, 18.16, 16.32, -18.04, 14.72, -18.56, 6.56, 
14.28, 53.16, 41.28, 35.04, -40.68, -12.12, -5.91999999999999, 
22.32, 11.8, -16.44, -6.75999999999999, -36.2, 3.19999999999999, 
-8.12, -12.68, -0.08, 3.76, 2.64, -3.28, -0.48, 13.68, 11.2, 
10.16, 9.31999999999999, -15.04, -6.28, -22.56, 14.56, -5.72000000000003, 
53.16, 36.28, 45.04, -12.68, -0.120000000000005, 21.08, -24.68, 
-10.2, -17.44, 3.24000000000001, 8.80000000000001, -11.8, -26.12, 
-27.68, -0.08, 2.76, 0.640000000000001, 2.72, -4.48, -2.32, -4.8, 
18.16, 7.31999999999999, 12.96, 45.72, 37.44, -22.44, 9.27999999999997, 
36.16, 51.28, 7.04000000000002, 54.32, 5.88, -1.91999999999999, 
25.32, 27.8, 15.56, 22.24, 18.8, -38.8, 31.88, 31.32, -0.08, 
6.76, -0.359999999999999, -0.279999999999999, 1.52, 1.68, -3.8, 
18.16, -8.68000000000001, 7.96000000000001, -7.28, 30.44, 12.56, 
51.28, 9.16000000000003, 16.28, -14.96, 50.32, -18.12, -32.92, 
10.32, -8.19999999999999, -5.44, 22.24, 23.8, 33.2, -12.12, 51.32, 
-0.08, -4.24, -2.36, -0.279999999999999, -2.48, -4.32, -4.8, 
0.159999999999997, -17.68, 7.96000000000001, 9.72, 9.44, 1.56, 
-15.72, 4.16000000000003, 6.27999999999997, -28.96, -38.68, -18.12, 
-36.92, -34.68, -25.2, -23.44, -43.76, -59.2, -37.8, -54.12, 
-61.68, -0.08, 0.76, 2.64, 9.72, -1.48, 2.68, 21.2, 13.16, -1.68000000000001, 
10.96, 20.72, 22.44, 23.56, 18.28, -3.83999999999997, -16.72, 
-19.96, 46.32, 47.88, 25.08, 0.319999999999993, 21.8, 14.56, 
32.24, 1.80000000000001, -5.80000000000001, -12.12, 1.31999999999999, 
-0.08, 5.76, -4.36, 4.72, -3.48, -5.32, 4.2, 4.16, -12.68, -14.04, 
-11.28, 0.439999999999998, -13.44, 25.28, 58.16, 29.28, 32.04, 
38.32, 14.88, 32.08, 39.32, 47.8, 16.56, 17.24, -25.2, 13.2, 
27.88, -6.68000000000001, -0.08, -6.24, -2.36, -6.28, -3.48, 
3.68, -1.8, -9.84, 11.32, 4.96000000000001, -26.28, -32.56, -38.44, 
-49.72, -62.84, -40.72, -20.96, -13.68, -52.12, -24.92, -49.68, 
-25.2, -19.44, -82.76, -36.2, -51.8, -60.12, -65.68, 0.92, -3.24, 
-1.36, -0.279999999999999, -19.48, -34.32, -22.8, 1.16, 19.32, 
-2.03999999999999, 27.72, 4.44, 12.56, -53.72, -35.84, -60.72, 
24.04, -15.68, 27.88, 11.08, 12.32, 33.8, 5.56, 3.24000000000001, 
24.8, -21.8, 18.88, -15.68, -0.08, -3.24, -1.36, -0.279999999999999, 
8.52, -5.32, 7.2, -12.84, 9.31999999999999, -0.039999999999992, 
-19.28, 13.44, -4.44, -5.72000000000003, -75.84, -82.72, -39.96, 
-60.68, 17.88, 23.08, 11.32, 38.8, 2.56, -6.75999999999999, 26.8, 
36.2, 27.88, 48.32, -0.08, -2.24, 1.64, 2.72, 2.52, -5.32, 0.200000000000003, 
-10.84, -4.68000000000001, -16.04, -15.28, -9.56, -27.44, -32.72, 
-63.84, -32.72, -49.96, -37.68, 38.88, 27.08, 7.31999999999999, 
5.80000000000001, 5.56, 10.24, -13.2, -20.8, 39.88, 36.32, -0.08, 
-3.24, 1.64, -9.28, -3.48, 1.68, -13.8, -2.84, -12.68, -15.04, 
8.72, 16.44, 7.56, 1.27999999999997, -23.84, -4.72000000000003, 
21.04, -22.68, -47.12, -16.92, -29.68, -32.2, -25.44, -40.76, 
-72.2, -50.8, -54.12, -99.68, -0.08, -4.24, 0.640000000000001, 
11.72, 4.52, -10.32, 1.2, 8.16, 15.32, -5.03999999999999, -14.28, 
-12.56, -34.44, -1.72000000000003, -11.84, -56.72, -25.96, -5.68000000000001, 
10.88, -4.91999999999999, 4.31999999999999, -40.2, 46.56, 20.24, 
5.80000000000001, 21.2, -1.12, 38.32, -0.08, -2.24, 2.64, -1.28, 
4.52, -1.32, -3.8, 1.16, 13.32, -0.039999999999992, 3.72, 2.44, 
19.56, 4.27999999999997, -41.84, -21.72, -29.96, 15.32, 39.88, 
-22.92, 28.32, -11.2, 67.56, 23.24, 25.8, -9.80000000000001, 
54.88, 18.32, -0.08, -1.24, 2.64, -1.28, 10.52, -4.32, -7.8, 
2.16, 16.32, -9.03999999999999, -0.280000000000001, 8.44, -47.44, 
-35.72, 51.16, 12.28, 15.04, 27.32, 19.88, 38.08, 50.32, 35.8, 
-16.44, 25.24, -1.19999999999999, 15.2, 25.88, 21.32, -0.08, 
-2.24, 1.64, 0.720000000000001, -0.48, 2.68, 6.2, -5.84, 13.32, 
11.96, -33.28, -32.56, -39.44, -50.72, 42.16, -38.72, -12.96, 
49.32, -4.12, -21.92, -13.68, -11.2, 2.56, 25.24, 16.8, 34.2, 
25.88, 56.32, -0.08, -2.24, -1.36, -6.28, 6.52, -4.32, -13.8, 
-12.84, -26.68, -15.04, -30.28, -0.560000000000002, 2.56, -28.72, 
58.16, 52.28, -51.96, -30.68, -36.12, -1.91999999999999, -56.68, 
-22.2, -26.44, -21.76, -27.2, -12.8, -58.12, -13.68), .Tsp = c(1, 
25.9642857142857, 28), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Even though the value of the likelihood is unique, it may differ by a constant in different software implementations. That is, the likelihood produced by software need not always equal the exact true likelihood. This is just a matter of convenience. Since the value of the likelihood is not very useful by itself, it does not matter much. The relevant application is comparing likelihoods of different models, that is, taking the difference of the likelihoods. As long as the constant is the same, it will cancel out when difference is taken.

Comment: Try estimating two models using the "forecast" package and the same two models using "dlm" package. The difference in the likelihoods of the two models should be the same regardless of the package.